# Multiple imputation: deleting cases before imputation

Tags: panel-data, missing-data, multiple-imputation

Note: The question has been edited to make it more focused, and the title has been changed to make it clearer.

I have read questions/answers about how to select *variables* for imputation. This question is how to select *the sample (rows)* that one should impute on, illustrated with the example of my dataset.

**Analysis model:** I have a longitudinal dataset with data collected at three time points. The analysis model involves using multiple variables at time 1 to predict one variable at time 3. The goal is to explain the relationship between variables.

**Imputation model:** I am doing multiple imputation to account for attrition in the dataset, on the assumption that data are MAR. I have observed variables at time 1 that explain the missingness at time 3. Although I can't really conclude they are not MNAR, I am proceeding with this assumption because from what I understand, it is better than doing complete case analysis. I have built the imputation model based on advice from van Buuren's book 'Flexible Imputation of Missing Data'.

**Missingness description:** Overall, the variable-wise missingness is 0-31% and the case-wise missingness is 0-94%. Say out of the dataset of $n = 15000$, there are around $1000$ cases for whom missingness is >50% and out of these, many individuals have not filled out the questionnaires (which are my predictors) at all. This means that there is not a single value available on my main predictor variables for these individuals. This can be called construct-level missingness (as opposed to item-level missingness or unit nonresponse). There are sporadic data points available on other auxiliary variables that are not of interest to me in the analysis, but which are included in the imputation model. The reason for the missingness on my predictor variables is perhaps random (e.g. skipping the page by accident), but we cannot be sure. There is also item-level missingness in the data, wherein a small number of individuals have not filled out a large number of items (80-90%).

**Question**

One aspect I am really getting stuck on is which sample I should start with i.e. should you start with the "raw" sample. I know that the whole point of MI is that one is not deleting cases. However, are there circumstances in which you do delete cases before imputation? For example:

- When cases have a very high percentage of missingness (>90%) on predictor variables at baseline
- When cases have construct-level missingness on predictor variables at baseline (i.e. entire questionnaires are not filled out and do not have *any* data on predictor variables, though they may have data on auxiliary variables)

I am particularly interested in knowing whether cases should be deleted, given that my main concern is attrition bias (and imputing the outcome variable) and missingness on the outcome *is* dependent on the value of the predictor in my dataset. Hence, by including cases with a lot of missing data on predictors *and* outcome, I am worried I am violating the premise of the MAR assumption.

I have the feeling I'm asking something fairly obvious and since I am new to understanding multiple imputation, it is not obvious to me. But I hope the question is relevant to others as well. Please advise if the question can be improved.

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on your goals? I.e. is your intention causal inference, prediction, something else?

Comment: The goal is explanation (explain the relationship between two variables). To some extent, it could be viewed as hoping to contribute to causal inference but causality cannot really be concluded as no variables were manipulated.